# Finding prime numbers using list comprehention

Tags: python, math, list-comprehension

I was trying to generate all prime numbers in range x to y. I tried simple example first: `range(10,11)` which means to check if 10 is a prime number:
Here is my code:

```
prime_list = [x for x in range(10, 11) for y in range(2,x) if x % x == 0 and x % 1 == 0 and x % y != 0]
```

I know that the thing is missing the option to tell the expression that `x%y != 0` should be checked for all y in `range (2,x)` and return true if and only if all have met this condition.

How do we do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check all elements (from 2 upto x-1) met conditions:

```
>>> [x for x in range(2, 20)
     if all(x % y for y in range(2, x//2))]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Comment: Could be better if it ran only upto sqrt(x). Nice use of `all`, I now know how many places I could've used it in.

Comment: You can use `range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1)`. (`int` is used to avoid `TypeError`)

Comment: Nice solution! Only thing is it shouldn't check to x. I got this one. Unfortunately, it doesn't get 2 as a prime number.:
[x for x in range(2,2000) if all([x % y for y in range(2,math.ceil(math.sqrt(x)) + 1)])]

Answer (score 3):

One way using set comprehension can be

```
list(set(range(2,11)) - {x for x in range(11) for y in range(2,x) if x%y == 0})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could optimize more using the concept of the square root so as not to iterate throughout the list and calculate the prime numbers faster in the following way!!

```
import math
[x for x in range(2, 21) if  all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x + 1)) ) )]
```

Answer (score 2):

Program to find prime numbers within a given range using list comprehensions:

```
min = 10

max = 100

primes = [num for num in range(min,max) if 0 not in [num%i for i in range(2,num//2)]]

print (primes)
```

Comment: in this code it considers 4 as prime, therefore the +1 is added in the second for `primes = [num for num in range(min,max) if 0 not in [num%i for i in range(2,num//2)+1]]`

Answer (score 1):

The version with filter:

```
filter(lambda x:all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x)), range(2, 13))
```

Answer (score 1):

@falsetru's answer is correct. But also, attention should be paid to optimized code. As someone said in the the comments in Kasra's answer

```
In [227]: %timeit [x for x in range(4, 1000) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(m.sqrt(x)) + 1))]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.08 ms per loop

In [228]: %timeit [x for x in range(4, 1000) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, int(m.sqrt(x)) + 1))]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.09 ms per loop

In [229]: %timeit [x for x in range(4, 1000) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x-1))]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop

In [230]: %timeit [x for x in range(4, 1000) if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x-1))]
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: The code which using `sqrt` is wrong. It returns non-prime numbers. It should be something like `int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The code can be shortened to one line using lambda function:

```
prime = list(filter(lambda x:all(x % y !=0 for y in range(2,x)),range(2,11)))
print(prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for finding prime numbers upto given range.

```
>>> lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))

>>> upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))

>>> [x for x in range(lower, upper+1) if x>1 if all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2, x))]
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers using the same list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for generating prime numbers up to 1000! The same can be used for any range.

```
primes = [num for num in range(2,1000) if True not in [True for divisor in range(2,(int(num/2)+1)) if num % divisor == 0 and num != 2]]
```