# Return list of primes up to n using for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, list, primes

I have just picked up learing python and I am trying to create a simple function which accepts an integer and returns a list of all primes from 2 to that integer.

I have created the function but code doesn't seem to work. I have found solutions only for more efficient (and complex) methodes (like this one [Finding prime numbers using list comprehention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045518/finding-prime-numbers-using-list-comprehention)) for this problem which don't really help me in finding my mistake.

```
def list_of_primes(n):
    primes = []
    for y in range (2, n):
        for z in range(2, y):
            if y % x == 0:
                continue
            else:
                primes.append(y)
        primes.sort()
        return primes
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Your `return` should be outside the `for`.

Comment: what's this `x` in your if statement again?

Comment: Thank you Johnny!
for the record there was another mistake in line if there should be z instead of x.

However there seems to be another problem - when given an integer 10 it returns folowing list:
[3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]

Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: Note: since you are generating primes in order, there is no need to sort.

Comment: What does "code doesn't *seem* to work" mean? Does it work or doesn't it work? Why don't you know whether it works or not?

Comment: "code doesn't seem to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. Below is a working implementation of your algorithm.

```
def list_of_primes(n):
    primes = []
    for y in range (2, n):
        for z in range(2, y):
            if y % z == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(y)
    primes.sort()
    return primes

list_of_primes(20)

# [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

**Explanation**

- Indentation is *crucial* in Python.
- You need to test if `y` is divisible by `z`, not by a variable `x` which has not been defined.
- Sort your list and return at the very end, both *outside* your outer `for` loop.
- Use `break` to skip a number when it is found to be non-prime.
- Apply your `else` statement on the inner `for` loop, not as part of the `if` / `else` clause.

Comment: @jpp: I can't let that pass :) just `for z in range(2,int(y**0.5)+1)` else you're wasting CPU power looking for divisors that cannot exist.

Answer (score 3):

jpp answer fixes the problem, but it can be improved by making the inner loop go only to square root of the candidate (plus one for perfect squares).

That's a common mistake, which wastes a lot of CPU power trying to find divisors that don't exist. That turns the algorithm from `O(n**2)` to `O(n**1.5)`

```
def list_of_primes(n):
    primes = []
    for y in range (2, n) :
        for z in range(2, int(y**0.5)+1):
            if y % z == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(y)
    return sorted(primes)
```

Still using the `else` in `for` loop if `break` isn't reached trick, and in the end returns `sorted(primes)` instead of performing in place sort then return.

But the best way to generate a big list of prime numbers is *not* using a primality test in a loop, but it's the [Sieve of Erathosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004407/a-fast-prime-number-sieve-in-python) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corrected version of your code (didn't test, but should work):

```
def list_of_primes(upper_bound):
    primes = []
    for candidate in range(2, upper_bound):
        is_prime = True
        for divisor in range(2, candidate):
            if candidate % divisor == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break  # no need to test any further
        if is_prime:
            primes.append(candidate)
    return primes
```

Comment: same remark: inner loop should go up to square root of candidate + 1

Comment: Indeed, but OP wanted just a correction of their algorithm, so I didn't want to complicate things by adding any extra logic / improvements.